# Tipping Questions

Tags: discussion

I wish to ask a question about tipping in a specific situation but in my own country (UK), so no Travel is involved, hence I presume Travel.SE is not appropriate.

Can anyone advise me if there is an SE that is suited to this? The closest I could find was as an Etiquette one but that hasn't entered beta yet.

Comment: If people travelling to your country from abroad are likely to need an answer to the same question then it would still be on topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, Travel-SE is suited for that sort of question. Even though in your case no travel takes place, tipping culture issues pop up all the time when people travel, so if you can imagine someone from another country having the same problem, just go ahead and ask, it should go fine.

Provided, of course, the particular scenario is somewhat relevant to travellers in the same situation, but I can't see at the moment situation when it won't be.

We do have quite a bit of questions related to tipping: [tipping](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tipping) should have them all, so check if your particular question has already been answered before.

Comment: It's a bit tenuous that someone might have this issue.. holding a small post wedding dinner (two dozen) at a restaurant.. but I guess people do have weddings abroad. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Paul: well, in that case, probably might not be: but generalize the question to ask for the tipping etiquette for a formal event, and you might get some answers.

Answer (score 7):

Travel needn't be international to be [on-topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

So, assuming you're not asking about tipping in your own house, ask away!

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have a question about tipping inside my own house...Guess I better propose a new site on Area 51!

Comment: The mind boggles.

Answer (score 1):

If your question would be of interest to MANY travellers, it would be on topic.

You don't need to be one of those travellers.